# Overlays with images in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

I would like to implement the following ``Algorithm" in one SLIDE !

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Step 1: Show some text 
    \begin{itemize}
    Step 2 \item  show this item (text) 
    Step 3 Show the image  % Image want to be in a central position
    Step 4 Hide the image 
    step 5 \item Show a new item (text) 
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are some ways to achieve this: Jumping `\item` must be prevented by introducing place holders (e.g. `\vphantom)

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \onslide<1->{Theory on Brontosaurs}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<2->  Brontosaurs are huge

    \only<3>{%
      \includegraphics{beeduck}%
    }%
    \onslide<4->{%
      \vphantom{\includegraphics{beeduck}}%
    }%
  \item<4> Brontosaurs do not look like bee ducks 
  \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there: take advantage that many of standard commands (`\item`, `\includegraphics`, for example) are overlay-aware in `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Show some text 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<2->  show this item (text) 
    {\par\centering\includegraphics<3>[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\par}
    \item<4-> Show a new item (text) 
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

By the way, `serif` as class option is obsolete; you should use

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

instead, as I did in my example.